# Cannot delete primary key constraint in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, primary-key

When I open designer for a table in SSMS, first column Id has a primary key assigned to it (`IDENTITY`), and key icon is shown next to it. In the Indexes / Keys window I can see a `PK_dbo.Lines` entry with Name `[PK_dbo.Lines]` and type `Primary Key`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Lines DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Lines]
```

returns

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
>   'PK_dbo.Lines' is not a constraint.

If I execute

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
```

I can see primary keys for all tables, except for table `Lines`...

This query also does not return any results:

```
select object_name (parent_obj) ObjectName, name
from sysobjects
where xtype = 'PK'
  and parent_obj = (object_id('[dbo].[Lines]'))
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: If you make any changes to tables / columns in a database SSMS needs to be **manually** refreshed in order to correctly reflect these changes. Could it be that it is as simple as right-clicking on `Tables` and select refresh?

Comment: I tried to simulate your situation and everything works well. Please provide your table full script.

Comment: @Ralph You were correct, but it seems that not only needs to be refreshed, but also close the designer window, and then reopen it again. It seems that when whenever you show window Indexes / Keys, it shows the data when the designer was loaded, and it will not refresh the data until the designer was closed and reopened. Post your suggestion as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make any changes to tables / columns in a database SSMS needs to be manually refreshed in order to correctly reflect these changes. Could it be that it is as simple as right-clicking on Tables and select refresh?

Alternatively, you might have spelled the PK name incorrectly? Please try the following script to remove the PK from the table 'Lines':

```
declare @PK_Name nvarchar(200);
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max);

select  @PK_Name = (
                    select  i.name as IndexName
                    from    sys.indexes as i
                    inner join sys.index_columns as ic
                    on      i.object_id = ic.object_id
                            and i.index_id = ic.index_id
                    inner join sys.tables as t
                    on      t.object_id = i.object_id
                    where   i.is_primary_key = 1
                            and t.name = N'Lines'
                   )

set @strSQL = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.Lines DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @PK_Name

execute(@strSQL)
```

First the script retrieves the correct name for the PK and then it tries to drop the PK constraint.

Comment: To anyone in the same situation, don't forget also to close and reopen table designer!